# Is there a way to make Webstorm beta 9 do live expression updates in angular?

Tags: angularjs, webstorm

I can debug my AngularJS app with chrome and when I change text in a

tag for example the text changes as I type it.  However, if I have an expression like {{1+1}} and change that to {{1+2}} what I see is the raw expression and not the evaluated one.

is this something I'm doing wrong or does webstorm not support it.

**Edit: I just create a short video to show what I mean
https://www.dropbox.com/s/2wnu969hi1ykxv0/webstorm9angularlive.mp4?dl=0

Answer (score 0):

Known issue, please follow [WEB-6471](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-6471) for updates

Comment: I've found that in v9 beta, it sometimes works.  see this video:

Comment: actually, I already posted the updated video above in the edit. that seems to show expressions working but not directives.